# getting date of all SATURDAY and SUNDAY in a particular year in C#?

Tags: c#, date

How do I get the date of all **sunday** and **saturday** in a particular year and count the result in C#.
I've searched a lot but only in java gives me result how abut in C#?

Comment: Any effort so far to solve it?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928083/to-get-the-mondays-to-saturdays-in-the-current-month) which can easily be a duplicate with a loop

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already have some code, but you should check [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @All: I'll think of it next time.